# How can I go to anchor and open a Bootstrap collapse at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have spent about twelve hours on this and can't get it working. I have a webpage that displays uploaded content. The page has a collapsed form that the users can open to edit their info and re-upload. They click on the “edit” button to make the form visible and this all works fine.

In some cases, the users will be happy with their input, but may want only to upload more photos. I have another button that should make the form collapse and then scroll down to an anchor tag at the bottom of the form which has userfile labels and browse buttons to locate their photos.

I have found Bootstrap and JS code for this (at Stack Overflow) and haven't been able to make it work. The trouble for the developer that posted the question was the same as mine; and the developer, Michele Milidoni said this would collapse the target HTML section and then scroll to the anchor tag. Looking at the code, it looks correct to me. The JavaScript function is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#jump").on(“shown.bs.collapse”, function () {
        window.location = "#photos";
    });
});
```

I have tried half a dozen versions of this function (every iteration I could find on the web) using scrollTo, hash, location.href, etc., etc. The Bootstrap  is:

```
<div id="jump" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#live_form">
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="#photos">Upload more photos</a>
</div>
```

And the target section of HTML is wrapped in this div:

```
<div id="photos">
   <!-- html here -->
<div>
```

I have tried some fifteen versions of the bootstrap code without success. The section collapses in every case, but won’t scroll down to the anchor tag. Also, I input the JS code into jslint and JavaScript Tester Online without solving the problem. Jslint required 'use strick' and returned only, `<< ready>>() global jQuery` and `<<on>>() global window` which has turned up nothing when googling that output.

Same is true for JavaScript Tester Online which returned “Result is an object, look at the console.” There doesn't seem to be a website that has any explanation of this output either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I believe the issue is with the JavaScript, but and can't get this running and have no idea what direction to turn next.

Comment: are those quotes `“` in your original code?

Comment: Hi Jeff, the original had single quotes, but jslint require double quotes to run without generating a warning. I ran the code both ways without success.

Comment: double quotes `"` are different to `“`!

Comment: Got it. I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeff, I did just upgrade to a new OS and didn't even think of checking if "smart quotes" were being produced by the Mac. I changed that back to 0x22 neutral quotes, but the behavior is the same. Thanks for pointing that out though, I never would have thought that it had changed.